# Problem in merging two sorted arrays using pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, merge

I am trying to merge two sorted arrays using pointers. The third loop is working food upto first arr[5] but then show garbage values afterwards. is the sorting techniqure wrong or am I using pointers incorrectly?

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;


int main() {
    int arr1[] = { 1,3,4,6 };
    int arr2[] = { 2,3,4,5 };
    int n1 = 4;
    int n2 = 4;
    int arr3[10];
    int* endptr = &arr1[0];
    int* endptr2 = &arr2[0];
    int* endptr3 = arr3;
    int k = 0;

   
    while (endptr < &arr1[n1-1] &&endptr2  < &arr2[n2-1]) {
        if (endptr[0] < endptr2[0]) {
            endptr3[k++] = endptr[0];
            endptr++;
        }
            
        else {
            endptr3[k++] = endptr2[0];
            endptr2++;
        }
    }
    while (endptr < &arr1[n1 - 1]) {
        endptr3[k++] = endptr[0];
        endptr++;
    }

    while (endptr2 < &arr2[n2 - 1]) {
        endptr3[k++] = endptr[0];
        endptr2++;
    }
    cout << arr3[5];
}
```

I got the results up to first 6 elements and then get garbage values.

Comment: what is "garbage" ? please include output  and expected output in the question

Comment: It should be `&arr1[n1]` (or more simply `arr1+n1`). Your version ignores the last element of each array.

Comment: `enptr[0]` is just `*endptr`. I would suggest to not mix pointer arithmetics and `[]` too much, but stick with one. in general `arr[i]` is the same as `*(arr + i)`

Comment: To be clear `endptr <= &arr1[n1-1]` would be ok, but if you are using `<` then it should be `endptr < &arr1[n1]`. And of course the reason you only get 6 values is that you are only considering the first three elements of each array,

Comment: In your last while loop you have `endptr3[k++] = endptr[0];` based on the variable naming I would expect this to be `endptr3[k++] = endptr2[0];`

Comment: @john yep that was the problem, thanks

Comment: @user20716902 Yes that was a mistake, I corrected it thanks

Comment: The boundary conditions are completely wrong. If you take out a piece of paper, and work it out whether it should really be, for example, `endptr < &arr1[n1-1]` or `endptr < &arr1[n1]`, the results will surprise you.

Answer (score 4):

The way you are using the pointers is negatively affecting your thought process.

Let’s abstract it to a function to help make it cleaner:

```
void merge(
  int * first1, int * last1,  // elements of array1
  int * first2, int * last2,  // elements of array2
  int * dest )                // where to put sorted data
```

This is the “iterator” idiom used by C++ algorithms. `first` points to the first element. `last` points to *one-past* the last element. (And we assume that `dest` points to enough space to contain the results.) So:

```
int array1[] = { 1,3,4,6 };
int array2[] = { 2,3,4,5,7 };
int array3[9];  // enough room for array1+array2

merge( 
  array1, array1+4,  // first array has 4 elements
  array2, array2+5,  // second array has 5 elements
  array3 );          // destination array has 4+5=9 elements
```

C++ actually gives us a couple of functions to get the first and last pointers to whatever underlying sequence container you’ve got:

```
merge(
  std::begin(array1), std::end(array1),
  std::begin(array2), std::end(array2),
  std::begin(array3) );
```

Now we can reconsider our merge algorithm.

```
void merge(...)
{
  // while both array1 and array2 have elements:
  while ((first1 != last1) and (first2 != last2))
  {
    if (*first2 < *first1)
      *dest++ = *first2++;
    else
      *dest++ = *first1++;
  }

  // if array1 has any leftover elements:
  while (first1 != last1)
    *dest++ = *first1++;

  // if array2 has any leftover elements:
  while (first2 != last2)
    *dest++ = *first2++;
}
```

In particular, notice:

- We can easily check whether an array has elements by comparing the `first` and `last` pointers directly. When `first == last`, there are no elements, since `last` is one-past the end of the source array.
- Comparison is simple enough. We *could* have written that as `if (first2[0] < first1[0])` but that is less idiomatic than just using the `*` operator.
- Copying a value is as simple as a dereference and increment on both sides of the assignment.
- The three loops of the merge all work on a simple “are there elements left?” check.

Note also how we kept the test condition to a strict less-than comparison. That has ramifications for generic programming (for example, merge sorting in non-increasing order), but I’ll leave it at that for today...